# How to store the stored procedures in TFS

Tags: visual-studio-2008, sql-server-2008

HI all,

Iam using VS2008 and SQL2008 i want to access my stored procedures in VS2008 TFS so please tel me the steps to do it.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I usually have Database project stored inside my source control repository that contains all the scripts necessary to create a new database, all the tables, views , sp's etc.

Generating scripts for SP's is quite easy.  Simply open up the Server Explorer and connect to you database, sekect any existing sp and drag it onto the database project in the project browser window.

Answer (score 1):

Use the GDR R2 project: [Microsoft® Visual Studio Team System 2008 Database Edition GDR R2](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=bb3ad767-5f69-4db9-b1c9-8f55759846ed&displaylang=en)

If you don't have Team System, then use the built-in database project.

[Handling Database easily with Visual Studio 2008](http://www.vitalygorn.com/blog/post/2008/01/Handling-Database-easily-with-Visual-Studio-2008.aspx)